# How to remove a specific package from dependency list of another package?

Tags: apt, dependencies, qt

Since I'm using Qt5 I want to uninstall all the qt4 libs. I tried it with the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove libqt4-*
```

which attempts to remove all the qt4 libs but in addition it wants to remove `texlive` and `vlc` which I don't want to be uninstalled.

Is there a way to keep those two packages? I found `apt-mark hold` but then they wouldn't be updated, too, so that doesn't suit for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those packages still use `qt4` that is why they want to be removed, they depend on it.

There are many packages that still use `qt4` for there interface, just because `qt5` is  available, it does not make `qt4` obsolete, you can have both without issue.

I would recommend you keep `qt4` as you may face issues with other applications that use `qt4` and not `qt5`down the line.

Why do some packages still use `qt4`?

It is a lot of work to update your interface to a new language, as Ubuntu can support both versions at the same time and the difference to the end user is minimal, it is simply not a priority to update it with such a superficial update.